# Opencv Clustering On More Than 4 Channels

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, k-means

I am trying to apply the kmeans clustering algorithm in opencv library (kmeans2) , but each sample point have more than 4 values
(more than 4 features)

when i try to use cvMat to prepare the parameters for kmeans2 it raises an exception whenever i print or assign any values to it.

here are the two ways i have tried

The first method

```
import cv
from numpy import *
a = zeros([20,1,6])
b = cv.fromarray(a)
print b[0,0]
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The number of channels must be 1, 2, 3 or 4) in cvRawDataToScalar, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 1531
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: The number of channels must be 1, 2, 3 or 4
```

The second method

```
import cv
from numpy import *
a = cv.CreateMat(20,1,cv.MAKETYPE(cv.CV_32F,6))
print a[0,0]
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The number of channels must be 1, 2, 3 or 4) in cvRawDataToScalar, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 1531
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: The number of channels must be 1, 2, 3 or 4
```

what is the correct way to create and manipulate the cvMat parameter for the kmeans algorithm ?

Comment: although I have no idea about the opencv python interface, in both cases, you have a 20 by 1 by 6 matrix, meaning your number of channels is 6 so it does not work?

Comment: no it doesn't work , although i can create Matrices with more than 4 channels they don't work with kmeans... the solution was to create matrices with one channel but the width (no of cols) == features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you're making is forming matrices of wrong dimensions. Change this

```
a = zeros([20,1,6])
```

to this

```
a = zeros([20,6,1])
```

and this

```
a = cv.CreateMat(20,1,cv.MAKETYPE(cv.CV_32F,6))
```

to this

```
a = cv.CreateMat(20, 6, cv.CV_32F)
```

It seems you have misunderstood the documentation

> samples – Floating-point matrix of input samples, one row per sample.

and in each column you have the features.

Comment: i didn't misunderstood the documentation , i tried that solution and didn't work, but the reason was that some feature have nan values which caused some errors , after fixing that it worked, thanks

Comment: i was following that tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/a/8813320/37980 which made me believe that i have to use the channels for the feature vector